# For every $h \in \mathbb R^n$ the limit $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac 1 t \big(f(x_0 + th)-f(x_0)\big)$ exists and is equal to $D_{f_{x_0}}(h)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose $U \subset \mathbb R^n$ is open and $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb R^m$ is differentiable in $x_0 \in U$.

I want to show that for every $h \in \mathbb R^n$ the limit $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac 1 t \big(f(x_0 + th)-f(x_0)\big)$ exists and is equal to $D_{f_{x_0}}(h)$.

I've made the following considerations:

I can write $h = \sum a_i e_i$. Then $$D_{f_{x_0}}(h) = D_{f_{x_0}}\left(\sum a_i e_i\right) = \sum a_i D_{f_{x_0}}(e_i) = \sum a_i \left(\frac {\partial f_i} {\partial x_1}, \ldots, \frac {\partial f_i} {\partial x_n}\right)^T.$$

But how can I see that the limit $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac 1 t \big(f(x_0 + th)-f(x_0)\big)$ exists and equals the above linear transformation? It would be easier if $f$ were a linear function.

Comment: What is $f_{x_0}$? And what is $D_{f_{x_0}}$ supposed to denote?

Comment: The linear transformation corresponding to $f$ at the point $x_0$.

Comment: If any of the answeres below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) all answers you find useful and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

What follows is for $m=1$. For arbitrary $m$ the argument is componentwise.

Denote $L$ the differential of $f$ at $x_0$. That the differential does exist means by definition that the following limit exists:
$$
\lim_{u\to0}\frac{f(x_0+u)-f(x_0)-L(u)}{\|u\|}=0.
$$
Now fix any $h\ne0$ and for $t\to0$ we get $u=th\to0$. From the above limit we get
$$
0=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{f(x_0+th)-f(x_0)-L(th)}{\|th\|}=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{f(x_0+th)-f(x_0)-tL(h)}{|t|\|h\|}.
$$
Equivalently:
$$
0=\frac{1}{\|h\|}\lim_{t\to0}\Big|\frac{f(x_0+th)-f(x_0)-tL(h)}{t}\Big|=\frac{1}{\|h\|}
\lim_{t\to0}\Big|\frac{f(x_0+th)-f(x_0)}{t}-L(h)\Big|.
$$
Since $\|h\|\ne0$ we conclude
$$
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{f(x_0+th)-f(x_0)}{t}=L(h),
$$
as wanted.

Note: the other computations you suggest in fact help to see that in case directional derivatives define a linear form $L$, then that linear form is *escalar product with the gradient*. But this doesn't yet means the function is differentiable: this only comes from the limit stated at the beginning.